# How to test container's width/height size

Tags: testing, flutter, containers, size

I'm trying to test the width and height of a container. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
expect(
        find.byWidgetPredicate((Widget widget) =>
            widget is Container  && widget.width == 48),
        findsOneWidget);
```

but. unfortunately, if I type `widget.width`, it will say that the getter width isn't defined for the class Container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such property in `Container`. Instead, it holds a `BoxConstraints` with the minimum and maximum width of the `Container`. Assuming that `minWidth` and `maxWidth` are equal in your case, consider using:

```dart
expect(
  find.byWidgetPredicate((Widget widget) {
    if (widget is Container) {
      BoxConstraints width = widget.constraints.widthConstraints();
      return (width.minWidth == width.maxWidth) && (width.minWidth == 48);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }),
  findsOneWidget,
);
```

For the height:

```dart
expect(
  find.byWidgetPredicate((Widget widget) {
    if (widget is Container) {
      BoxConstraints height = widget.constraints.heightConstraints();
      return (height.minHeight == height.maxHeight) && (height.minHeight == 48);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }),
  findsOneWidget,
);
```

Comment: very neat and insightful!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
widget.constraints.widthConstraints();
```